# CheckNonZeroSender

Tags: signed-extensions

Why is `CheckNonZeroSender` a signed extension rather than part of the `UncheckedExtrinsic::check()` when checking the payload for a bad proof?  What exactly does the non-zero check do?  It appears to be checking all the bytes to see if they are zero?

```
if who.using_encoded(|d| d.iter().all(|x| *x == 0)) {
    return Err(TransactionValidityError::Invalid(InvalidTransaction::BadSigner))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this because the all-zero address is a 'well-known' key.

It is dangerous, and people love to use the default value. Maybe get an account from `Vec::default()` in some corner cases.

So we forbid using this address to send transactions.

And you might want to learn more detail about the all-zero address.

[Why does the all 0 public key have a known private key in SR25519 and ED25519?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/982/why-does-the-all-0-public-key-have-a-known-private-key-in-sr25519-and-ed25519)

Comment: It's only "dangerous" because BTC and ETH people adopted a flawed convention.  hash-to-curve was always the sensible solution because it lets you encode a non-spendable messages, like the reason why you burned tokens.  If I just burn to zero then maybe I can benefit from the burn in multiple ways in unrelated applications, which then makes the burn insecure.

Answer (score 2):

`sr25519` and `ed25519` the private key for the all-zeros-public-key is known. However, in `ecdsa` this isn't the case and people used the all-zeros-public-key as destination when they wanted to "burn" tokens, aka make them inaccessible. To mimic the same behavior, there exists this `CheckNonZeroSender` extension in Substrate.